# MySQL: Update with nested subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, nested, subquery

I'm trying to make this query work. The aim is to get the minimum date between a list of minimum dates.

But I'm getting: *Unknown column 'di.device_id' in 'where clause'*

How can I expose the device_id field to be visible inside the second subquery?

```sql
update device_information di
set first_seen=(
  select min(date) from (
    select min(insert_date) date from product_state_change_event where device_id=di.device_id
    union select min(insert_date) date from sensor_range_switch_change_event where device_id=di.device_id
  ) as dates
);
```

**Edited**

In fact, I have 19 tables to *union* them.

Comment: And what issue are you getting?

Comment: correlation can only occur within 1 level.  since you have 2 nested queries ddi.device_ID is not availalbe

Comment: In fact, I have a lot of tables to check, not only `product_state_change_event` and `sensor_range_switch_change_event`, so it will be a lot of *union*.

Comment: Could you not simply have a table of events, which stored what the event was, and when it occurred?

Comment: @Strawberry We started having one table, but we are dealing with hundred of millions of events, and growing up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone want to know how I solved it:

```
update device_information di
join (
  select identifier, min(date) date from (
    select client_var_name identifier, min(insert_date) date from product_state_change_event group by client_var_name
    union all select client_var_name identifier, min(insert_date) date from sensor_range_switch_change_event group by client_var_name
    ...
  ) as unique_dates group by identifier
) as dates on di.identifier = dates.identifier
set di.first_seen = dates.date;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would expect a query such as this:

```
update device_information di join
       (select min(insert_date) as minid
        from product_state_change_event psce
        group by psce.device_id 
       ) psce
       on psce.device_id = di.device_id
    set first_seen = least(psce.insert_date, psce.minid);
```

This assumes that the dates are never `NULL`.  That is easily incorporated into the answer (by adding more logic to the `least()`).

Comment: Great! It's a very good approach. My problem is that I have a lot of tables, not only `product_state_change_event`. In the example, I only put two, but I have 19 tables to *union*. And if there is a NULL date, a need the first NOT NULL

Comment: @Agorreca . . . This answers the question you asked.  If you have a more complicated question, then ask *another* question with more details and relevant info.  It would be rude to modify this question, because the modifications might invalidate this answer and attract downvotes.

Comment: I disagree with that. The main question is a subquery with union inside. The edited part only remark that there are 19 'unions' instead of 2

Comment: I don't know if you can see the revisions, but I didn't replace anything in the text, only add the title **Edited** and the text below, because I suppose maybe you missed the _union_ part.